# Fazendo consulta em mais de 1 campo com FindBy no spring mvc

Tags: java, mvc, spring

Tenho este repositório:

```
public interface RepositorioUsuarioPermissao extends JpaRepository<UsuarioPermissao, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM UsuarioPermissao u WHERE u.id_seletivo = ?1 and u.id_usuario = ?2")
    List<UsuarioPermissao> findById_seletivoAndId_usuario(Long id_seletivo, Long id_usuario);    
}
```

Faço a chamada da Query acima assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adicionar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adicionar(@ModelAttribute("usuariopermissao") UsuarioPermissao usuariopermissaoNovo, Model model) {
      List<UsuarioPermissao> usuariopermissaolista = repositorioUsuarioPermissao.
      findById_seletivoAndId_usuario(usuariopermissaoNovo.getSeletivo(),
      usuariopermissaoNovo.getNivelusuario()); // para buscar só o seletivo e usuario selecionado
}
```

Tenho a Entidade:

```
public class UsuarioPermissao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "upm_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "upm_id_usuario")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "upm_id_seletivo")
    private Seletivo seletivo;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "upm_id_permissao")
    private NivelUsuario nivelusuario;    


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public NivelUsuario getNivelusuario() {
        return nivelusuario;
    }

    public void setNivelusuario(NivelUsuario nivelusuario) {
        this.nivelusuario = nivelusuario;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }


    public Seletivo getSeletivo() {
        return seletivo;
    }

    public void setSeletivo(Seletivo seletivo) {
        this.seletivo = seletivo;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        UsuarioPermissao other = (UsuarioPermissao) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Está dando erro na hora de chamar a função:

```
List<UsuarioPermissao> usuariopermissaolista = repositorioUsuarioPermissao.
      findById_seletivoAndId_usuario(usuariopermissaoNovo.getSeletivo(),
      usuariopermissaoNovo.getNivelusuario());
```

Fica vermelho esta parte: `findById_seletivoAndId_usuario`

Comment: O método `findById_seletivoAndId_usuario` recebe dois parâmetros do tipo `Long`. Mas `getSeletivo()` e `getNivelusuario()` não retornam um `Long`, e sim instâncias de `Seletivo` e `NivelUsuario` (que não são `Long`), daí o erro

Comment: Qual erro está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 1):

Os dois parâmetros do método `findById_seletivoAndId_usuario` são do tipo `Long`.

Porém, na chamada você está passando para o segundo parâmetro o resultado de `usuariopermissaoNovo.getNivelusuario()`, mas o retorno desse método é do tipo `NivelUsuario` e não `Long`.

Por isso o problema.

Passe um `Long` ao invés de `NivelUsuario` e o erro deixará de existir.